# When using different view controllers (portrait and landscape) to handle orientation changes, is a segue the most appropriate way to handle this?

Tags: ios, segue, screen-orientation

I have been looking into ways of setting up separate landscape and portrait view controllers to handle a changing orientation.  The code posted below is from Apple stating how to do this.  I noticed they use performSegueWithIdentifier.  It seems odd that a segue is being used.

In order to create a segue on the storyboard I'm assuming I must create a hidden button and drag the connection from the portrait to the landscape view controller.  I can then set the segue identifier to "DisplayAlternateView". What is the default segue animation?  Or is the default to turn the animation off?

Also why is this code in the awakeFromNib method?  Shouldn't it be in viewDidLoad?  Is awakeFromNib called before viewDidLoad?

Also I'm assuming I must have a different target action for every scene of my storyboard.  If I have portrait view A, B and C with a corresponding landscape view A, B and C, should I have the following changes to the Apple code

on my A view:

```
   selector:@selector(orientationChangedA:)
```

then on my B

```
   selector:@selector(orientationChangedB:)
```

then on my C

```
   selector:@selector(orientationChangedC:)
```

This way each method can perform it's own segue.

I feel like I might be over complicating things here.  Are the separate segues causing me to do extra work or is this how how orientation switching to separate view controllers normally handled?

Here is the code from Apple saying how to handle orientation changes with different view controllers:

```
@implementation PortraitViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib

{

isShowingLandscapeView = NO;

[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)

                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification

                             object:nil];

}



- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification

{

UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&

    !isShowingLandscapeView)

{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplayAlternateView" sender:self];

    isShowingLandscapeView = YES;

}

else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&

         isShowingLandscapeView)

{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;

}

}
```